# No splash activity is showing

Tags: android

I have built a `SplashActivity` to be displayed for `5500` ms before the `MainActivity`. But when the app runs, it just shows a white screen for 2s, then jumps to the `MainActivity`. No error is being displayed, but there is no splash screen design or animation or anything else.

Here is the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"></activity>
   <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
</application>
```

This is my `SplashActivity`:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView appName;
    Animation frombottom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 5500);

        appName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appName);
        frombottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.frombottom);
        appName.setAnimation(frombottom);
    }
}
```

What could be the possible problem and the solution to that? Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Your splashscreen should get the launcher intent.

Answer (score 2):

In Launcher you have called MainActivity thats the reason your splash screen open

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"></activity>
  <activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manifest file needs to be changed

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Sorry, it immediately terminates the app, `Application terminated.`

Comment: Any error coming in logcat??
 This code should run 100%

Comment: No error in the log. Just says `Application terminated`.

Comment: You should use animation listener and when the animation finishes then you need to call MainActivity. This is the right way to handle this scenerio. Also you need to mention intent filter for splash activity in manifest.

Answer (score -1):

Making an `Activity` to do a "fixed" splash screen is not the right way to go.

Use an drawable or make one from xml, for example (bg_launch.xml):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/primary"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

From you main theme create a launch theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_launch</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

then from you manifest apply this theme to your  main Activity

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     ...
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
...
```

Finally revert you your default theme when app start from your main Activity

```
@Override
void onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle){
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Doing this way you'll have no white screen delay, you can still go for an `Activity` splash screen if you need animation or translated text but you'll get that drawback to have a little delay before it's actually present to user.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But if the splash screen presents the way that I've designed (with the animations and other stuff), I'm fine with the delay, but what could be the reason for no splash screen at all?